# Implementing MVC using objective-c with storyboards

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, storyboard

I am a bit confused on how to implement an MVC pattern using Object-C and storyboards. In particular, it seems to me that the view controller should have a direct reference to its view but when using storyboards I can only create a view reference from the storyboard to my apps MainViewController using ctrl-click in XCode. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem.  A view controller does have an outlet named "view" which is connected to its main view.  If you create subviews, those can also be controller outlets.  ...?

Comment: @Phillip Mills: That is what I am confused about. It seems that a arbitrary view controller should own a reference to the view its controlling. Instead, it appears that storyboarding requires that a view's outlet be owned by the MainViewController.

Comment: A controller should be handling its own view(s).  Can you describe the case where you're restricted to a MainViewController?

Comment: In the case where the app is wholly contained in 1 page and the page contains several view (tables and so on). My thought is to create a controller for each view and have the controllers own a specific view. The only was I have been able to do this so far is to pass a reference to a view's controller from the MainViewController which does not feel correct to me (I am fairly new to Cocoa programming after years of Windows development).

Comment: I would consider one controller per view to be overkill.  Typically, a controller was responsible for one logically-related screen of information: one main view and however many subviews that made sense.  A few years ago, container views became common as part of designs.  Those are views that define a subset of the screen space that is managed by its own child controller.  Usually, container views are reserved for cases where the child controller may be replaced by a different child but they could be used only to divide responsibility.

Comment: By the way, is this for iOS?  View controllers in Mac applications are a fairly new concept and have their own -- often unexpected -- behaviors.